# R Assign Same Value to Multiple Elements of a Vector

Tags: r, loops, vector, element

I have trouble assigning the same value to the multiple elements of a vector. Here is my non-working example:

```
dog <- c()
year <- c(1980,1990)
for (i in 1:2){
     dog[(i*1):(i*12)]<- unique(year)[i]
}
```

I want the `dog` vector to have twelve 1980 and twelve 1990. But instead I get a 1980 and 1990 followed by 22 NAs. What's the next step?

Comment: `dog <- rep(c(1980, 1990), each = 12)` ?

Comment: A couple of notes regarding your code: (1) It's better to pre-allocate your vectors (if you know its final "length") before looping and modifying it; e.g. see `x1 = c(); x2 = rep(NA, 1e5); system.time(for(i in 1:1e5) x1[i] = i); system.time(for(i in 1:1e5) x2[i] = i); identical(x1, x2)`. (2) Avoid calling the same function inside the loop many times if you could just call it once - here, you could save `unique(year)` in a variable before looping and just _use_ it inseide your loop.

Comment: (3) This specific task does not need a loop but, I guess, you could use something like `dog[(((i - 1) * 12) + 1):(i * 12)]` to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you unroll the loop, what you're doing is

```
dog <- c()
year <- c(1980,1990)
dog[1:12]<- unique(year)[1]
dog[2:24]<- unique(year)[2]
```

which is

```
 [1] 1980 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990
[11] 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990
[21] 1990 1990 1990 1990
```

the second assignment pretty much overwrites everything. I'm not sure if you want the values to alternate or if you want the values grouped together, but you can easily create such a vector with

```
rep(year, each=12)
#  [1] 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980
# [11] 1980 1980 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990
# [21] 1990 1990 1990 1990
```

or

```
rep(year, times=12)
#  [1] 1980 1990 1980 1990 1980 1990 1980 1990 1980 1990
# [11] 1980 1990 1980 1990 1980 1990 1980 1990 1980 1990
# [21] 1980 1990 1980 1990
```